# jQuery hide/show div, with radio button control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have few radio buttons with same name.

```
Office <input type="radio" name="owner_type" value="0" />
Agent <input type="radio" name="owner_type" value="1" />
```

and have part of jQuery code, which must show or hide part of code.

```
$('[name="owner_type"]').change(function(){
    if ($('[name="owner_type"]').val() == 1) {
        alert("it's 1 now");
        $('#agents').show();
    } else {
        alert("it's 0 now");
        $('#agents').hide();
    }
});
```

Alerts was added for debugging. It's always alert about 0. No matter which radio is checked now. I am hope, you can help me. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('[name="owner_type"]').change(function () {
    if ($('[name="owner_type"]:checked').val() === "1") {
        alert("it's 1 now");
        $('#agents').show();
    } else {
        alert("it's 0 now");
        $('#agents').hide();
    }
});
```

Actually, you are doing this:

```
$('[name="owner_type"]').val()
```

which will always fetch you the value of the first radio button, whether it's checked or not.

In order, to get the value of the *checked* radio button on `change` event you can use the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector as above.

Comment: Thank you man. It's Working now. I can't upvote your post. Not enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

```
var $oTypes = $('input[name="owner_type"]').change(function () {
    //$('#agents').toggle($oTypes.filter(':checked').val() == 1);
    $('#agents').toggle(this.value == 1);
});
```

1. Use the element selector before attribute selector
2. Use toggle to set the display state

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
            $('input[name="owner_type"]').change(function(){
                if (this.value == 1) {
                    alert("it's 1 now");
                    $('#agents').show();
                } else {
                    alert("it's 0 now");
                    $('#agents').hide();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use a `:checked` selector

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z9H3Z/)

```
$('[name="owner_type"]').change(function(){
    if($('[name="owner_type"]:checked').val() == 1) {
        alert("it's 1 now");
    $('#agents').show();
    } else {
        alert("it's 0 now");
    $('#agents').hide();
    }
});
```